# PHP Laravel How to prevent float from removing zero after point?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In mysql databse table i have double type column and it having values like
10.12 , 15.88 , 10.00 etc

While getting all these values it return response
10.12
15.88
10

I wants to keep  .00 for the value 10.00 but it only gives 10 .?
Tried it with float and double type
It works fine with decimal type but value returns with double quotes "10.00" So it considered as string
I need it as float type or double type

Comment: then in db you can set  type like `double(10,2)`

Comment: @DevsiOdedra in db I have set exactly like double(10,2)

Comment: can you post the schema for the table and the SQL statement for how you are "return"ing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel's Attribute Casting https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting. Your model's `$casts` property provides a convenient method of converting attributes to common data types.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'column_name' => 'decimal:2',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Great!! @Chirag and It will be good if you verify the answer for community.